# Updated version of ViewPager with indicator for use in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, viewpagerindicator

I'm trying to make a small slide show that you can swipe through and has a circle indicator of which page you are on out of the total number of pages. Currently I'm trying to make Cheesebaron's ViewPagerIndicator work. https://github.com/Cheesebaron/ViewPagerIndicator with has been ported over from a 3 year old project https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

However, After adding V4 support Xamarin says that ViewPager is deprecated. Is there an up to date way of implementing this type of slide show and indicator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been released a new package by James Montemagno: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PagerSlidingTabStrip-for-Xamarin.Android

Comment: I don't see the a circle page indicator right of the bat. Would I have to implement this myself? I need an indicator like you see when browsing applications

Comment: I am not sure i fully understand what you mean, but in general everything that is possible with the library of JakeWharton is also possible in the one from James. Showing some kind of indication is just a matter of added that to your axml.

Comment: I see what you mean. This package places the indicator under the current tab. I just need to figure out how do draw the indicator as a filled in circle for the selected page and the online of a circle for non selected pages.

Comment: @FieldsCage Have you figured this out yet, I need to do that same thing.

Comment: Sorry @cfl but I think I ended up just removing the indicators from my design and just used the library as is.

Comment: @FieldsCage Thanks though. I found a way to use the indicator but without requiring fragments. I just include layouts into the main view and show/hide then as user clicks